# Android: Can we add recyclerview dynamically in layout

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Like any other dynamic view we can add that view dynamically into layout, is it possible with recyclerview that we can add/create dynamically and attach into a viewgroup?

Thanks

Comment: Of course we can, show us what you've tried so far!

Comment: I havent found resources about this

Comment: I'm getting 647.000 results on Google on `add recyclerview dynamically`. Are you 100% sure you didn't find any resource about this?

Comment: before posting any question you should try once to find solution.

Comment: @Zun the results are for adding content dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams lparams = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = new RecyclerView(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutParams(lparams);

    rootview.addView(recyclerView);
```

Here `rootview` is linear layout or any other view group of your layout XML file after that you can add Adapter to this recycle view as usual. Here you can add any number of recycle view using `rootview.addView(recyclerView);`

Comment: Thanks @Ashish Kakadiya